# get selected id of kendo drop down value

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

how to get id of selected name from dropdown.
whene select `Apples` then got id `1`and select `Oranges` then `2`.
this is simple kendo dropdown example.

```
<body>
            <input id="dropdownlist" />

            <script>
                $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
                  dataSource: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
                  ],
                  dataTextField: "name",
                  dataValueField: "id",
                  index: 1,
                  select: onSelect
                });

                function onSelect(e) {
                console.log(e);
                  };
            </script>
</body>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In order to retrieve the selected Id you can use the `dataItem` object and access the id within it with `change` event:

```
 var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
 $('#id').text(dataItem.id);
```

This will get you access to any data within the object too:

```
$('#name').text(dataItem.name);
```

**Working example**

http://jsfiddle.net/ygBq8/1/

**Html**

```
<input id="dropdownlist" /><br/>
<span id="id" >Id</span><br/>
<span id="name" >Name</span><br/>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
                  dataSource: [
                    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
                    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
                  ],
                  dataTextField: "name",
                  dataValueField: "id",
                  index: 1,
                  change: onChange
                });

                function onChange(e) {
                   var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
                   $('#id').text(dataItem.id);
                   $('#name').text(dataItem.name);
                  };
```

Answer (score 3):

The Select event is a bit more difficult one to use, as that event fires before the item is selected.

If you use the Change event, you should be able to get the dataItem with

```
this.dataSource.get(this.value())
```

See sample http://jsbin.com/OcOzIxI/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

Please use this.dataItem()

```
function onSelect(e) {
    alert(this.dataItem().id);
    alert(this.dataItem().Name);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To select ID of the selected item use:

```
$("#dropdownlist").val()
```

And to select TEXT of the selected item use:

```
$("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").text()
```